# Find instance based on value in the pipeline

Tags: webmethods

In my current project I need to check if a process Instance already exist. I should be able to check this against a value which is stored in the pipeline.
In WmMonitor I tried a few services but with none I was able to find the existing process.

Do I need to mark the pipeline variable as logged field to be able to find the process instance?

Mayeb someone can share an example?

Regards Dirk

Comment: How you want to use that? Why you need to check that? Why is it bad to have more process instances?

Comment: Otherwise I could create processes with the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to mark the field as a 'logged field' in order to be able to search for process instances with a certain value in this field. Use services from the package WmMonitor.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long, so I used answer instead of comment.

As of my understanding, you have some data, for simplicity assume, that just one string represents the data. Let say this is in a DB table. You should have flag in same table - `processed` with values true/false (in DB typically 0/1) and there should be a scheduler creating processes for unprocessed data only.

So the pseudo code would be:

```
retrieve unprocessed data
    for each record try to create process
    if creation was successful, mark the data as processed and continue
```

in this scenario you do not need to check whether process was started already...

Feel free to comment if something is unclear ;-)